# Change regex-builder-mode hook to use <C-s>

Tags: regular-expressions

I recently discovered emacs's "regex-builder" mode and am absolutely loving it. However, there doesn't seem to be an easy way to type in an expression in the "RE-Bulider" buffer and use that expression to search for matches.

My use case for regexp-builder is currently to write a regular expression, and once I see some matches, I scan through the document manually to see all the matching strings. I currently use the "string" regex syntax for my regexp-builder, as recommended [here](https://www.masteringemacs.org/article/re-builder-interactive-regexp-builder), so I don't think I would need to modify the `reb-lisp-mode` hooks.

Right now, if I type in an expression in the RE-Builder buffer and press `C-M-s` or `C-M-r` (isearch forward/backward regexp), I get whichever regular expression I used with `isearch` last, which is oftentimes different than what I'm currently searching for. Additionally, these isearch commands only perform their search on the current buffer, which happens to be the regex-builder buffer, which leads to no matches being performed on the buffer I want to search.

What I want to do is to bind the `C-s` and `C-r` keys to `re-search-forward` and `re-search-backward` functions on the buffer I'm searching in whenever I begin using the regex builder.

I've made the following function in my `~/.emacs`, but after evaluating the buffer, putting an expression in the `RE Builder` buffer and pressing the corresponding shortcuts, I still get `isearch-forward`, the default behavior.

```
(require 're-builder)
(setq reb-re-syntax 'string)

;; Improve regex searching through regexp builder
(defun regexp-builder-mode-config()
  "For use in `reb-mode-hook'."
  (local-set-key (kbd "C-s") 're-search-forward)
  (local-set-key (kbd "C-r") 're-search-backward)
  )
(add-hook 'reb-mode-hook 'regexp-builder-mode-config)
```

Essentially, what I want this to do is two-fold:

1. Once I make a regular expression, press the key combination `<C-s>` or `<C-r>` and be able to search for a regular expression in the buffer.
2. Solve the problem of emacs implicitly converting from one syntax (string) to the other (read). When I copy the expression I'm building to the kill ring `(C-c C-w)`, emacs adds a bunch of extraneous backslashes (which I presume is due to how it handles regular expressions in the interactive buffer), which makes my regex not work anymore.

At the moment, I believe I'm close to solving the first point, which is being able to edit a regex and then conveniently search for it in the buffer I'm working on. However, when I press `C-s` or `C-r`, I get the usual `isearch-forward/backward` functionality I'm trying to avoid, almost as if me changing the hook didn't affect anything.

I checked the documentation, and I'm fairly sure I'm using the correct hook, but any and all help is welcome!

Comment: As well as `reb-mode` note that there's also `reb-lisp-mode` which is used for the `rx` and `sregex` syntax options; so you might not have the right mode hook for your use-case.

Comment: That said, I'm not sure what you expect calling `re-search-forward` to do?  It's not going to automatically use the regexp you're building, and you're going to be searching in the `*RE-Builder*` buffer, not in the original buffer.  Unless that really is what you're wanting to do, I think you should update the question to describe the functionality you're trying to achieve, rather than just the details of an approach which may not actually be applicable.

Comment: Thank you! I have since expanded on the problem I'm facing. Hopefully it's a bit clearer now!

Comment: If you can copy the resulting regexp then you can paste into Isearch at the end of your search string, using `M-y`.

Comment: If I were you, I'd just use `C-c C-s` and `C-c C-r` which are bound to
`reb-next-match` and `reb-prev-match` to move between the matches. (Of
course you could rebind those functions to `C-s` and `C-r`.)